# What is more effective iterate a list and call a function or pass the list to the function

Tags: python, algorithm, list, dictionary

i have a list filled with dictionaries and for each dict i want to apply a function. What's is more effectiv or best practice, to iterate the list and pass the dict to the function for each iteration. Like shown here:

```
dict1 = {"foo": 8, "bar": 4, "baz":2}
dict2 = {"foo": 3, "bar": 6, "baz":3}
...

dict_list = [dict1, dict2, ...]

def function_iterate(dict):
    ...

for dict in dict_list:
    function_iterate(dict)
```

Or is it better to pass the list and iterate within the function:

```
dict1 = {"foo": 8, "bar": 4, "baz":2}
dict2 = {"foo": 3, "bar": 6, "baz":3}
...
dict_list = [dict1, dict2, ...]


def function_iterate(dict_list):
    for dict in dict_list:
        ...

function_iterate(dict_list)
```

Or maybe u know a other approach. If both methods are same effective, which one do u prefer and why?

Comment: if function is for this dictionary only then you can use anonymous function inside map for one line solution  _map(lamda dict_list: defination of function, dict_list)_

Comment: Both don't differ in _effectivity_: producing a result that is wanted, as per Merriam-Webster's. Choose on readability & ease of use. ("Obvious" differences in efficiency may be levelled out or inverted, depending on execution environment. _If_ you experience a performance problem, _and_ profiling points to such source consuming a non-trivial amount of time, re-profile with alternatives.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance wise , sending the whole list in would be faster, as function calls in python are expensive (performance wise).

Example of timing tests -

Code -

```
l = [{1:2},{2:3},{3:4}]

def func1(d):
        for k in d:
                d[k] += 1

def func2(l):
        for d in l:
                for k in d:
                        d[k] += 1
```

Timing results -

```
In [29]: %%timeit
   ....: for d in l:
   ....:     func1(d)
   ....:
The slowest run took 7.57 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.16 µs per loop

In [30]: %%timeit
   ....: func2(l)
   ....:
The slowest run took 9.25 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
1000000 loops, best of 3: 988 ns per loop

In [31]: %%timeit
   ....: [func1(d) for d in l]
   ....:
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.98 µs per loop

In [33]: %%timeit
   ....: list(map(func1,l))
   ....:
The slowest run took 4.42 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.5 µs per loop
```

---

For readability, `map()` would be better, as it is more readable. Example -

For Python 3.x -

```
list(map(function, list_of_dicts))
```

For Python 2.x -

```
map(function, list_of_dicts)
```

Comment: Ok, what would be faster `map()` or passing the whole list?

Comment: The whole list, atleast in python 3.4 where I tested.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map`:

```
map(function, dict_list)
```

`map` is a builtin python function : https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map

Comment: Yeah this could be one further solution, but sometimes i just have just one dict, this is where map is getting ugly